# Beamer column citations

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I have two columns and I am citing in each one:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bm}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}

\bibliography{refs}


\begin{document}
   \frame{\frametitle{Title}
   \begin{columns}[2]
   \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
       \footnotemark
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
       \footnotemark
   \end{column}
   \end{columns}
   \footcitetext{cocco}
   \footcitetext{kirkpatrick}
   }
\end{document}
```

The problem is that at the bottom of the page both citations have the same number:2, while in the first column there is 1, in the second 2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `\footcitetext{cocco}` soon after the first `\end{column}`

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bm}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}

\bibliography{refs}


\begin{document}
   \frame{\frametitle{Title}
   \begin{columns}[2]
   \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
       \footnotemark
   \end{column}
   \footcitetext{cocco}   %% <--- move this here.
   \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
       \footnotemark
   \end{column}
   \end{columns}   
   \footcitetext{kirkpatrick}
   }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Because the `\footcitetext` takes the number from previous `\footnotemark` which is 2 for both `\footcitetext` commands. Hence, it should be

```
\footnotemark
.
.
\footcitetext
.
.
.
\footnotemark
.
.
\footcitetext
```

to achieve correct numbering.

Comment: What if more than one citation should be placed within one `column` environment?